# Помогите написать function angular

Tags: angularjs, функции

Привет, необходима функция которая будет срабатывать при событии ng-click. Есть объект, в нем массив от 1-10 выводятся они с помощью ng-repiat в диве. Надо чтоб при нажатии на любой из выведенного массива срабатывала функция которая будет понимать на какой из массивов было нажато и выводить для каждого из массива свой template. Благодарю!

angular

```
myApp.controller('dragCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.draggableObjects = [{name:'Подписан через..'}, 
                               {name:'Ссылка кликнуть?'}, 
                               {name:'Письмо открыто?'}, 
                               {name:'Особый перевод'},
                               {name:'Изменено значение..'},
                               {name:'Письмо отправленно'},
                               ];
    $scope.draggableObjects2 = [{name:'Если баллы..'}, 
                               {name:'Если теги..'}, 
                               ];
    $scope.draggableObjects3 = [{name:'Купил'}, 
                               {name:'Бросил в корзину'}, 
                               {name:'Посетил URL'},
                               ];
    $scope.droppedObjects1 = [];
    // $scope.droppedObjects2= [];
    $scope.onDropComplete1=function(data,evt){
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
        $scope.droppedObjects1.push(data);
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function(item) {
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(item);

        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects1.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    $scope.handleClick = function(obj) {
      console.log(obj); 
    }
    var inArray = function(array, obj) {
        var index = array.indexOf(obj);
    }
  });
```

html

```
<div flex="80" class="container" ng-controller="dragCtrl">
    <div class="ngdropfool" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)">
      <div class="ngdrop"  ng-click="handleClick(obj)" md-whiteframe="2"  ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects1" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event)">
        {{obj.name}}
        <button id="button-icon" class="material-icons buttstyle" ng-click="removeItem(obj)">&#xE92B;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-object" ng-drag-clone="" md-whiteframe="2">
      {{clonedData.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://metanit.com/web/angular/2.9.php) пример

Comment: Ну тот как отследить какой obj активен с этим разобрались. В данный момент стоит вопрос в том как вывести для каждого obj свою область видимости.

Answer (score 1):

Просто передавай объект в функцию

в шаблоне

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-click="handleClick(item)">{{item.name}}</div>
```

в контроллере

```
$scope.handleClick = function(item) {
    console.log(item); // item - ваш объект из массива.
}
```

Comment: вроде работает, только в моем случае вместо item я так понимаю надо obj выше добавил код

Comment: А теперь я так понимаю мне можно вывести определенный template в зависимости от $$hashKey ?

Comment: @ОлегНормпасан не знаю что вы подразумеваете под template, но $$hashKey это служебное свойство и используется кране редко, а то и никогда.